# Execute host shell script from meteor container

Tags: docker

I have shell script on my host. I've installed docker container with meteord image. I have it running, however I would like to execute this shell script inside meteord docker image. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is possible but you will have to copy the script in the container as follow:

```
docker cp <script> <container-name/id>:<path>
docker exec <container-name/id> <path>/<script>
```

For example:

```
docker cp script.sh silly_nightingale:/root
docker exec silly_nightingale /root/script.sh
```

Just make sure the script has executable permissions. Also, you can copy the script at build time in `Dockerfile` and run it using `exec` afterwards.

**Updated:**

You can also try `docker volume` for it as follow:

```
docker run -d -v  /absolute/path/to/script/dir:/path/in/container <IMAGE>
```

Now run the script as follow:

```
docker exec -it <Container-name>  bash /path/in/container/script.sh
```

Afterwards you will be able to see the generated files in `/absolute/path/to/script/dir` on host. Also, make sure to use absolute paths in scripts and commands to avoid redirection issues. I hope it helps.

Comment: That will not work for me unfortunately. Shell script execute python code which generates files, and I need to keep those files on host, not in a docker, because these files will disappear from docker container after deployment.

Comment: what about you create the container with a volume mounted from the host, using `-v`. The volume directory can have your script now run the script in your container. After execution your files will be accessible at host. Let me know if you want an example.

Comment: Hi Qasim, thank you for update. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me. As I mentioned in my first description of the problem I would like to execute that script from inside the meteor container. I cannot use "docker" command as docker is not installed in this container. I know that I can communicate within the host by using following bind0 IP address: 172.17.0.1.

Comment: @wlodi83 you can access the container shell by running following command on host where docker daemon is running `docker exec -it <Container-name>` .  Once you have shell just start application using script. The command I mentioned should be ran from host not from the container.